# Java classloader: How to replace a method of a 3pp class

Tags: java, classloader

I try to replace a method in a 3pp class, which is invoked by another 3pp class. 
I know if I rewrite the hole class, and modify the class path order; or put it into the lib/ext of the java home than the extension class loader will load my class instead of the original.

But how can I extend the original class from the replacement class:

```
package com.example
public class Foo extends com.example.Foo {
    @Override
    public void m1() {
    }
}
```

I know this example is not working, but I try to describe the goal: this class extends the original class with the same canonical name, one method has been overridden and all the other methods are inherited. So if we increase the version of the 3pp product, we do not need to modify our class, because we override only that method, what we want to cover.

Have anybody a good solution or a good idea?

Comment: What is 3pp class? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing is a very hard thing, If you are working on a web application, it will not works if the class you're trying to extend is used inside the library, because if in your JAR you have a class *SomeService* that use the class *Foo* the classloader will load the class inside the JAR.
Another stuff is that is not so good override the class in this way, what I can suggest to do is use *AOP* to override that method.
If you are using spring it have a powerfull system to do it http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html, but it works just inside a spring context.
Otherwise you can use *AspectJ* (sincerely I've never used it).

Last thing, is this class used just insde the 3pp library?

Comment: Yes, it used inside the 3pp lib only.

Comment: mmm if you try to do a class with the same name and package you have to write the entire class you can't just extend the same (because of the class loader that will extend the same class, and it is impossible). The only thing I can suggest so is use AspectJ to intercept the method call and instead of call that method use your own